# How can you correctly combine lineno and paracol?

Tags: pdftex, line-numbering

When a paragraph inside paracol is split up over multiple pages all the line numbers show up at the top of the page where the paragraph has ended instead of next to the line they belong to. The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{internallinenumbers}
\vspace{10pt}
\lipsum[1-3]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{internallinenumbers}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: lineno and paracol incompatibility]

Is it possible to make this display correctly, or are those two packages just plain incompatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\linenumbers` and `\nolinenumbers` instead of `\internallinenumbers`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\begin{paracol}{2}
\vspace{10pt}
\lipsum[1-3]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{paracol}
\nolinenumbers

\end{document}
```

[image]